# Using existing cookies from outside the browser

Tags: c#

Ii want to download a file from site that need to be  log-in.

So i think if i use my browser to log-in and store cookie on hdd.

Is it possible to download file with that cookie ?

(its impossible to get cookie with program, anti-bot, etc)

Comment: If there is a login-form you will probably get a session-specific cookie, which means that you will have to get it from the webpage each time you want to use your application. Have you looked at doing the login in your app and use HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer or similar?

Comment: i used this `cookieJar.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name.Trim(), cookie.Value.Trim(), cookie.Path, cookie.Domain));` and its worked !

Answer (score 0):

everything you can do with your browser you can also do in a program, so if you want a program to download the file, authenticate with the program and let the program receive the cookie.

Comment: so why something like anti-bot , captcha created ? are they created for fun ?

Comment: They are created to raise the bar on what needs to be done to circumvent them. There's a huge difference between just requesting an URI or passing the expected values first.